# Optimize by getting data as single array versus separate columns

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script below which calls separately for column G and I of a spreadsheet and returns the last non-zero value in the specific column.

I am wondering if it is faster to call for an array of data from columns G, H and I (is that called an array?) and retrieve the last non-zero value in column G and I? How can I do that?

```
// get the latest value for Column G
var lastRow = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Form responses 1").getLastRow();
var columnGvalues = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Form responses 1").getRange("G" + "1:" + "G" + lastRow).getValues();
for (; columnGvalues[lastRow - 1] == "" && lastRow > 0; lastRow--) {}
var columnGLast = columnGvalues[lastRow - 1];

// get the latest value for Column I
var lastRow = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Form responses 1").getLastRow();
var columnIvalues = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Form responses 1").getRange("I" + "1:" + "I" + lastRow).getValues();
for (; columnIvalues[lastRow - 1] == "" && lastRow > 0; lastRow--) {}
var columnILast = columnIvalues[lastRow - 1];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which is faster, it will strongly depend on how much data you have in those columns (and in H too)

There are 3 possibilities:

1 - You have very few data: using a single array from G to I will be faster (but then, it wouldn't matter at all, everything would be fast)

2 - You have moderate data and one of the columns has a lot of empty cells related to the other. Your approach is a good one.

3 - You have huge data. Then each `getValues()` will take long, it would be better to go cell by cell (provided you do not have one of the two columns with a great number of empty cells)

If you have really huge data, it will be faster to get the last line and do range offsets upwards.

Repeated getRanges and offsets are usually slower than a getValues(), but if you have tons of data, getValues will be slower. (Because get values would always take the entire column, and going cell by cell would take only the necessary data).

But what would be considered huge data and small data?? Only speed tests could tell...

So, for huge data:

```
function mainFunction()
{
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  var columnGLast = getLast(sheet, "G", lastRow);
  var columnILast = getLast(sheet, "I", lastRow);
}

function getLast(sheet, column, row)
{    
    var currCell = sheet.getRange(column + row);

    while (currCell.getValue() === "" && row > 1)
    {
       row--;
       currCell = currCell.offset(-1,0);
    }

    return currCell.getValue();
}
```

Now, if your columns do not have that huge data, you can pick just one array:

```
function mainFunction()
{
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  var myRange = sheet.getRange("G1:I" + lastRow).getValues();

  var columnGLast = getLast(myRange, 0, lastRow - 1);
  var columnILast = getLast(myRange, 2, lastRow - 1);
}

function getLast(array, columnIndex, lastRow)
{    
    var val = array[lastRow][columnIndex];

    while (val === "" && lastRow > 0)
    { 
       lastRow--;
       val = array[lastRow][columnIndex];
    }

    return val;
}
```

Comment: Nice. I think I understand this conceptually. Should I be able to just paste this into google apps script after adding the line" var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();" and get it to work? I did that but it told me getRange(column + row) was undefined in the first solution and that array was undefined in the second. I am new to scripting so bear with me. Thank you.

Comment: Yes...the first one should work, tested it just now. But just in case, remember the `function getLast` must be separate from you main function, so I edited the script showing that. You have to only call `mainFunction`. -- The second one had a little problem with how to get the values from the array, and it's fixed and tested now.

Comment: The missing `row--` before would only be a problem if you had an entire empty column.

Answer (score 0):

So for this you get the values of each column(G and I) separately to two different array using the [getRange(row, column, numRows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer)) by adding the last row value to `numRows`.

Then you can easily find the last non zero value from those arrays.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Correct me if I am wrong, but I think what you have mentioned in your answer is essentially what the original code I posted was doing - calling 2 separate ranges and retrieving values from the 2 ranges. I was looking to see if it's faster to call a single more comprehensive range and then retrieve the values from a single array.